# Enable two scroll bars with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started to learn CSS and I want a page with two independent columns, each has a scroll bar. And my CSS is like (span4 and span8 are div class)

```
body { 
       height: 100%; 
       overflow: hidden; } 
.span4 {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto; }
.span8 { 
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto; }
```

It seems not working. I have to specify the height of span4 and span8, like "400px", but I don't want to do this (not responsible?, also I don't know the height). Do I miss something? If this can be done without JavaScript, that'll be good (I know little of js). Thanks.

Update: still can't figure it out. Here is a link to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/hPfKk/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to create a 'wrapper/box' around the row-fluid. With a few overrides to the Bootstrap CSS and a `position:absolute` container around the 2 spans/columns this should work..

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="column span4">

     <!-- left-side --->

    </div>
    <div class="column span8">

     <!-- right-side --->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add some Bootstrap CSS overrides, and tweak the .box and .column containers..

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.row-fluid {
    height: 100%;
}

.column:before, .column:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.column:after {
    clear: both;
}

.column {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.box {
    bottom: 0; /* increase for footer use */
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
}

.full {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo: http://bootply.com/60614**

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's really well thought.

Answer (score 1):

Set the html as height:100% as well.

```
html,body { 
       height: 100%; 
       overflow: hidden; 
} 

.span4 {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto; 
}
.span8 { 
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VerCp/

Comment: In your edit, there is only one column. When I add "<div class="row-fluid">" to make it two columns, the scroll-bar disappears... http://jsfiddle.net/hPfKk/2/

Answer (score -1):

I find my way to solve this using JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      windowHeight = $(window).height();
      $('.span4').height(windowHeight);
      $('.span8').height(windowHeight);
  });
```

And in the CSS, heights of span4 or span8 are no need to specific. JS is really powerful and I'll start to learn it next week.