# Double scrollbars in bootstrap-4 modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
$("div[id^='entry']").each(function(){
  
  var currentModal = $(this);
  
  //click next
  currentModal.find('.btn-next').click(function(){

    currentModal.modal('hide');
    currentModal.closest("div[id^='entry']").nextAll("div[id^='entry']").first().modal('show'); 
     
  });
  
  //click prev
  currentModal.find('.btn-prev').click(function(){
 
    currentModal.modal('hide');
    currentModal.closest("div[id^='entry']").prevAll("div[id^='entry']").first().modal('show'); 

  });

});
```

```css
    body.animsition.modal-open,body.animsition{
        padding-right: 0!important;
            overflow: hidden!important;

    }
    .modal.fade.show {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#data1">
                   View
                   </button>
                   <p>If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:</p>
     <div class="modal fade" id="data1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Trade Details</h3>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
                </div>
     
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="card-body card-block">
                      <div class="displaydata">
                         <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>
   
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary approve"   data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#entry02">Approve
                   </button>
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="modal fade" id="entry02" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                         <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Pre-Payments/LC's Report Detail</h3>
                                 
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         </button>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-body">
                         <div class="card-body card-block">
                            <div class="displaydata">
                               <table class="table table-bordered">
                                  <tbody>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
                                        <th scope="row">21st August</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">As per PI Cash/TT/Advance </th>
                                        <th scope="row">210</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Incoming/Outgoing LC Number/ Value</th>
                                        <th scope="row">20</th>
                                     </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                               </table>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev">Prev</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next">Next</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         
          <div class="modal fade" id="entry03" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                      <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sales and Purchase Report Detail</h3>
                              
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                   </div>

                   <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="card-body card-block">
                         <div class="displaydata">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                               <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                     <th scope="col">Purchase/Sales Invoice Date</th>
                                     <th scope="row">1st October</th>
                                  </tr>


                               </tbody>
                            </table>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev">Prev</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next">Next</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

I'm having double scrollbar while using bootstrap-4 modal. I've tried all the possible solutions (using jQuery and css)but I'm not able to achieve the result I want.

[image]

As you can see, there are two scrollbars. Even if I set the body overflow to auto when the modal is closed, and overflow hidden when the modal is open, one scroll bar appears but it shifts to the body content to the right. Since I'm using multiple bootstrap modals, after the multiple bootstrap modal is triggered,the modal-open class on body vanishes.

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369718/enable-two-scroll-bars-with-bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it's not the outcome I'm trying to acheive :)

Answer (score 1):

this is how I solve this issue... i am using this javascript to add and remove the `modal-open` on the `html` when I open/close the modal.

```
jQuery('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    jQuery("html").addClass("modal-open");
});
jQuery('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    jQuery("html").removeClass("modal-open");
});
```

for me the `html` needs to be **modal-open** that is gives the `overflow: hidden;`
style that hides the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be "modal-open" class that is not always add to `body` when you open your next modal (I think it is caused by your hide() & show() action triggered in the same time).

It is that class that remove the scrollbar to your body:

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Maybe I found a solution without touch your functions. My solution say to computer: "*Ehi, machine! Every time there are a modal show in a page put a class `modal-open` in `<body>`*".

To do this I used modal events, you can find the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

I added only this to your script, CSS is not necessary:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("body").addClass("modal-open");
});
```

```js
$("div[id^='entry']").each(function(){
     
        var currentModal = $(this);
  
        //click next
        currentModal.find('.btn-next').click(function(){

          currentModal.modal('hide');
          currentModal.closest("div[id^='entry']").nextAll("div[id^='entry']").first().modal('show'); 
           
        });
        
        //click prev
        currentModal.find('.btn-prev').click(function(){
       
          currentModal.modal('hide');
          currentModal.closest("div[id^='entry']").prevAll("div[id^='entry']").first().modal('show'); 

        });
     
    });

    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    });
```

```html
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#data1">
                   View
                   </button>
                   <p>If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:</p>
     <div class="modal fade modal-1" id="data1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Trade Details</h3>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
                </div>
     
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="card-body card-block">
                      <div class="displaydata">
                         <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>
   
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary approve" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#entry02">Approve
                   </button>
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="modal fade" id="entry02" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                         <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Pre-Payments/LC's Report Detail</h3>
                                 
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         </button>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-body">
                         <div class="card-body card-block">
                            <div class="displaydata">
                               <table class="table table-bordered">
                                  <tbody>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
                                        <th scope="row">21st August</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">As per PI Cash/TT/Advance </th>
                                        <th scope="row">210</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Incoming/Outgoing LC Number/ Value</th>
                                        <th scope="row">20</th>
                                     </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                               </table>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev">Prev</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next">Next</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         
          <div class="modal fade" id="entry03" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                      <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sales and Purchase Report Detail</h3>
                              
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                   </div>

                   <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="card-body card-block">
                         <div class="displaydata">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                               <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                     <th scope="col">Purchase/Sales Invoice Date</th>
                                     <th scope="row">1st October</th>
                                  </tr>


                               </tbody>
                            </table>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev">Prev</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next">Next</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

**EDIT 1**

Maybe I found a good solution! For this I cleaned a little your code, so you can understand better what's going on. I added comments to every function that I wrote. Be carefull, to make it simple I add "data-dismiss" attribute also to next & prev buttons. I removed your loop 'cause it is not necessary here and I created only one onClick event. I tested with Firefox, Chrome and IE11 on Windows and all work well.

Try it and if there is something that you don't understand, let me know in comments. :)

```js
var padding_right,
    currentModal,
    my_block;

$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  padding_right=$("body").css("padding-right"); /* create a variable with padding-right when modal is shown */
});

$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  /* This function is triggered when a modal is hidden and... */
  if($('.modal:visible').length) 
    $(document.body).addClass('modal-open').css("padding-right", padding_right); /* ...if there are some modal visible, it put on body class "model-open" & padding-right */
  else
    $(document.body).removeAttr("style"); /* ...if not remove only style attribute: having put "data-dismiss="modal on button next and prev modal.js automaticaly remove "modal-open" */
});


/* here I created only one function for our buttons, where I change only "my_block" with previus or next one. Your loop is not necessary */
$(".btn-next, .btn-prev").on("click", function(e){
  currentModal = $(this).closest(".modal");
  my_block= ($(this).hasClass("btn-next")) ? currentModal.nextAll("div[id^='entry']").first() : currentModal.prevAll("div[id^='entry']").first();

  my_block.modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#data1">
                   View
                   </button>
                   <p>If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap 4 yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

MaxCDN provides CDN support for Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. You must also include jQuery:</p>
     <div class="modal fade modal-1" id="data1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Trade Details</h3>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
                </div>
     
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="card-body card-block">
                      <div class="displaydata">
                         <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>
   
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary approve" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#entry02">Approve
                   </button>
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="modal fade" id="entry02" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                         <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Pre-Payments/LC's Report Detail</h3>
                                 
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         </button>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-body">
                         <div class="card-body card-block">
                            <div class="displaydata">
                               <table class="table table-bordered">
                                  <tbody>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
                                        <th scope="row">21st August</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">As per PI Cash/TT/Advance </th>
                                        <th scope="row">210</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Incoming/Outgoing LC Number/ Value</th>
                                        <th scope="row">20</th>
                                     </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>                               <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">Company</th>
                                  <th scope="row">Mark Company</th>
                               </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                               </table>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev" data-dismiss="modal">Prev</button> <!-- add data-dismiss here to close automatically modals -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button> <!-- add data-dismiss here to close automatically modals -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         
          <div class="modal fade" id="entry03" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                      <h3 class="modal-title title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sales and Purchase Report Detail</h3>
                              
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                   </div>

                   <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="card-body card-block">
                         <div class="displaydata">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                               <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                     <th scope="col">Purchase/Sales Invoice Date</th>
                                     <th scope="row">1st October</th>
                                  </tr>


                               </tbody>
                            </table>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev" data-dismiss="modal">Prev</button> <!-- add data-dismiss here to close automatically modals -->
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button> <!-- add data-dismiss here to close automatically modals -->
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Edit">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks,the problem of double scrollbar disappeared but when the modal content is greater than body content,the body content shifts to right.And when the modal content is less than the body content,the same problem plus the scrollbar appears and disappears :(

Comment: Mmmh... you are perfectly right,I had not noticed, I'm sorry. BTW, it is an interesting behavior. Now I have to go to work, but this evening I'll try to understand what's going on here. ;)

Comment: Sure,good day at work.Hopefully you will figure out what's going on in that code :)

Comment: I edited my answer. This time I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: Thank you so much,it worked perfectly fine.But when i close the modal,the whole screen goes blank.I guess I could figure that out myself.Once Again Thank you :)

Comment: Screen goes blank? I don't see that problem. BTW, you're welcome. :)

Comment: When I updated the function for next and prev button,the modals appear on top of each other (overlapping).And then when I add  currentModal.modal('hide'); in that function,the problem gets solved but again the shifting problem comes back .My mind has gone out of control.May be I am doing something stupid?:/.Also the function  $(document.body).removeAttr("style"); causes the whole screen to blank after modal is closed.

Comment: @samana ghimire, if you are using a different code from your first example, I can't help you. Maybe it is better if you put exaclty the code you are using in your question so we can help you better.

Comment: I think I'm using the same code as before but I don't know what is going on here.I will let you know after I figure out what mistake I am doing :)

Comment: With that code, as you can see in my snippet, all work well. Maybe it is a simple copy and paste problem. :/

Comment: yes  the snippet worked completely fine.The issue is caused by the local css and js(i think its a plugin) file which is causing the opacity of body to 0 when modal is closed  :/ but hope  I can fix that.I'll let you know when done. :)

Comment: yeah sure.Me too :)

Comment: Finally,I got the result as expected.I removed the plugin(It was not necessary) and added padding to the navbar header when modal class is open so that body doesnot shift.I was getting the shifting problem even though  I used $(document.body).removeAttr("style"); .But now its gone.Thank you for your help and support .

Comment: Nice, well done. This has become one of the most intricated question to which I replied in SO. When I'll go in Kathmandu remind me to give you the first prize! ;) Cheers &... Metal rules forever!! \m/

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to apply this in your CSS file?

```
html {
  overflow(x, y): hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us some code? Is hard to tell from that screenshot. Those double scrollbars are on the html right?

Comment: I have now attached code snippet.Hope this helps to understand

Comment: When applied this code, my entire page is missing the vertical scroll.